# Collecting entity attribute values with null for missing attributes in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have some entities in a table and their attributes and values in an other. I would like to create a select where I can see the value a specific attribute for every entity or null if that attribute is missing. How can I do this using standard SQL?

This is the setup:

```
create table person (id int not null, nick varchar(32) not null);

insert into person (id, nick) values (1, 'John');
insert into person (id, nick) values (2, 'Peter');

create table req_attributes (name varchar(32));

create table person_attributes (id int not null, 
                                person_id int not null,
                                attribute varchar(32) not null,
                                value varchar(64) not null);

insert into person_attributes values (1, 1, 'age', '21');
insert into person_attributes values (2, 1, 'hair', 'brown');
insert into person_attributes values (3, 2, 'age', '32');
insert into person_attributes values (4, 2, 'music', 'jazz');
```

And this is my current select statement:

```
select * from person join person_attributes on 
  person.id = person_attributes.person_id
  where attribute = 'hair';
```

Obviously Peter is not in the result set because we have no information about his hair. I would like to get him into the result set as well, but with null value.

The best would be if the result set was like

```
Person, Hair color
John,   brown
Peter,  null
```

I would like to avoid subqueries if possible, but if it is impossible to do with joins then they are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outer join will do this:

```
select p.*, pa.value
from person p
  left join person_attributes pa
         on p.id = pa.person_id
        and pa.attribute = 'hair';
```

Note that the condition for the "outer joined" table needs to go into the `JOIN` clause, not into the where clause. If the condition was in the `where` clause it would effectively turn the outer join into an inner join. This is because `pa.attribute` would be null due to the outer join, and the `where` would not match the null value thus eliminating all the rows that should actually stay in the result.

SQFiddle based on your example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d0342/1